# Question regarding bounds of integration for Joint Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am doing some questions regarding Joint Probability Distribution and i came across a problem that i am unsure of.

The random variables X and Y have a joint density function given by:

$f(x,y)$ = \begin{cases} 
\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x} & \text{if } 0 \leq x < \infty \text{ and } 0 \leq y \leq x \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Finding the Expectation of Y: E[Y]:
\begin{align*}
E[Y] &= \int_{0}^{\infty} yf_Y(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} y \left( \int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{-2x}}{x} \, dx \right) \, dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{-2x}}{x} \left( \int_{0}^{x} y \, dy \right) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-2x} \, dx = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

What i do not understand is why limits of the outer integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}$, instead of $\int_{y}^{\infty}$. Shouldn't $y$ be bounded by $x$ ?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense (because this would mean that $\mathbb E[Y]$ would depend on $y$.... The reason is that $$f_Y(y)=\int_y^\infty f(x,y)\,\mathrm d x$$ for all $y\geq 0$, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounds for the outer integral cannot depend on the bound variable of the inner integral; because those bounds are outside the scope of the inner integral.

Being inside the scope of the outer integral, the inner integral handles the relation between the bound variables.

$\quad y$ only "lives" inside $\int\ldots\mathrm d y$, so cannot appear outside of that.  $x$ "lives" everywhere inside $\int\ldots\mathrm d x$, so if that is the outer integral it is used to constrain the bounds of the inner integral relative to its value.  And vice versa.

$$\begin{align}
\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq x\} &=\{(x,y):y\in[0,\infty), x\in[y,\infty)\}\\&=\{(x,y):x\in[0,\infty), y\in [0,x]\}\\[3ex]\iint_{0\leq y\leq x} y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d (x,y) &= \int_0^\infty\int_0^x y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\ &= \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$